# How to get selected index in tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am using a table view. In the below method, I want to set the value of `appdelegate.page` to the value of table row index.

if row one is selected, then `appdelegate.page = 1`, if row two is selected, then `appdelegate.page = 2`... So what should I replace with index path in my code so that I will get the selected row index?

Here is my code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
  appDelegate.page = indexPath;//////what should i put here instead of indexpath    
  SecondViewController *svc = [[[SecondViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
  svc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve; 
  [self presentModalViewController:svc animated:YES];       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a Button in Cell of Table and set it's Tag with indexpath.row

Then Use:

```
-(IBAction)YourButton_TouchUpInside:(id)sender
{
}
```

Comment: i am using images on tablew view..is ther any other way, i can get the index?

Answer (score 0):

You would put indexPath.row or indexPath.item.

indexPath.item is preferred.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
appDelegate.page = indexPath.row;

SecondViewController *svc = [[[SecondViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
svc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve; 
[self presentModalViewController:svc animated:YES];

}
```

Use `indexPath.row` to get selected row value which will set up page property in app delegate.